# What does NOT char_pointer mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, char, logic, unary-operator

I was looking through code written by others and bumped into "if" I don't understand:

```
if (!buffer || len == 0)
```

in function

```
void getText(const char* objName, char* buffer, uint16_t len)
```

buffer, passed to function, is char array declared: char buff[10]={0};

What "!buffer" means? If it is bool it would make sense to me, but I have never seen before such statement as Not Char_Pointer. Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "not null". When you use any type with a logical operator, it is "contextually converted to `bool`", if possible, and for pointers the result of conversion is `true` iff the pointer is not null. See Boolean Conversions in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion for details.

I am assuming you are using C or C++ from the syntax, but in general you should tag questions with the programming language.